# Flattening recursive nested data in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have JSON data which contain multiple nesting as below. Depth of nesting is not fixed.

JSON field value

`{
  "hierarchy": {
    "record": {
      "id": 1,
      "record": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "record": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "record": [
                {
                  "id": 4,
                  "record": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 5,
                  "record": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "record": [
            {
              "id": 7
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "record"
}`

```
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).json(file.json)    
df.printSchema()
df.show(100,False)
```

This is the initial schema I get. I attempted explode but unable to solve the unknown dept of nesting it can have.

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
root
 |-- hierarchy: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- record: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- record: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- record: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- record: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- record: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|hierarchy                                                                                                                 |type  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|[[1,WrappedArray([2,WrappedArray([3,WrappedArray([4,WrappedArray()], [5,WrappedArray()])])], [6,WrappedArray([7,null])])]]|record|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

Want to get this flattened in the way that each record is turned in a row along with id and parent's id

```
record_field    id  parent_id
=============================
record          1   null
record          2   1
record          3   2

record          4   3
record          5   3

record          6   1
record          7   6
```

Is it possible to do this in spark sql (pyspark).

Comment: Did you check **explode** function of pyspark-sql ? And can you printSchema of your current dataframe please

Comment: tricky Updated my Question with schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may find it helpful
I ended up using recursion to achieve this.

```
def iter_cls(parentId, obj):
    if (len(obj)>0):
        for obj_item in obj:
            yield (parentId, obj_item.get("id"), obj_item.get("classifKey"))
            yield from iter_cls(obj_item.get("id"), obj_item.get("record"))

data = json.loads(str)
cls_data = data["hierarchy"]
top_cls = cls_data["record"]
top_cls_id = top_cls["id"]

listAll = ("{0}|{1}|{2}".format(ParendID,id,name)
        for (pid, id, name, clevel) in iter_cls(top_cls_id,top_cls["record"])
     )


df2 = spark.createDataFrame(listAll, StringType())

split_col = split("value", "\\|")

df2.select(split_col.getItem(0).alias("parentid")
          ,split_col.getItem(1).alias("current_id")
          ,split_col.getItem(2).alias("classifKey")
          ,split_col.getItem(3).alias("clevel")
        ).show()
```